# Errors installing mysql-python on Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, mysql-python

Unsure if I should be using Server Overflow or not... Using Django websites on Azure, deploying via GitHub... I have mysql-python in the requirements.txt and even went as far to add the site-packages to my application root... Getting the following error.

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with pyodbc. Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: unfortunately not :( ended up switching to AWS and using RDS instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to use the mysql-python binary install (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  After running pip install on the mysql .whl file I then copy everything starting with MySQLdb in the name from my default python install (C:\Python27) for me, to the virtualenv that I am using for my project.  I hope this might help.